# merging arrays that are pointers into one (of a different size), in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

EDIT:

```
int *combined;
combined = malloc(24 * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   combined[i] = 0;
}

decToBinary(theValue, &combined);
decToBinary(otherValue, &combined + 4);

int *decToBinary(int n, int *buff) {
    int i = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        buff[i] = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        i++;
    }
}
```

It has been forever since I have done C and I am playing around with Arduino code.  I was curious if it is possible to merge different sized arrays into one large one.

The arrays are a bunch of 4 element arrays I want to merge 6 of those into a 24 element array?

I got this far:

```
  int *someVal;  
  someVal = decToBinary(2); //returns my 4 element array

  //do the above to a different int* someVal1 6 other times...
  //then...
  int *combined; //24 'lights'
  combined = malloc(24 * sizeof(int));
```

Is it a `memcpy`? (Looking the doc on that doesn't seem I can piecewise use a memcopy to 'pack' it into the array). Do they have to be same size?  I would love a result like this:

```
[0,1,0,0]
[1,1,0,0]
[1,0,0,1]
[1,0,1,0]
[0,1,1,0]
[0,0,0,1]
```

To become:

```
[0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1]
```

I mean I could do this by iterating 6 times through each array and just setting each element of the large one on that with an external counter... just was looking for something more elegant.

Comment: Do you control the `decToBinary` interface and implementation? Why not modify or create one that writes the results to a caller supplied buffer, instead of allocating temporary arrays on the heap?

Comment: If plausible, write a version of `decToBinary` that accepts a 4-element array natively as an argument: I.e. `dec2BinaryAr(int val, int *ar)`, then just fire that on the six positions in the target array. I.e. `combined`, `combined+4`, etc.. In short, do your conversion straight into your combined array.

Comment: These are great ideas both (similar).  It is sort of fun diving into C again.  I do control the dec to binary!  So I just did that, but now I forget if I have to return the buffer or somehow use the address.... wow.  It is true if you don't use it you lose it.  Put the version up in the edit of OP

Comment: Your `decToBinary` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: This is true, I am unsure in C how to make it work by address and not by value, I thought I added it right with the & but I think I have them messed up

Comment: Suggest:  replace: `int *combined;
combined = malloc(24 * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   combined[i] = 0;
}`  with a single call to `calloc()`  As in: `int *combined = calloc( sizeof(int), 24 );  If( ! combined ) { handle error }`

Answer (score 0):

In this example I allocate 6 arrays of 4 int set to a same number (1, 2, 3...) and store them in an array of 6 pointers (someVals). Then I merge the 6 arrays in a single 24 elements array (combined) and print the result :

```
int * decToBinary(int n) {
    int *ar = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    for (char i=0; i<4; i++) ar[i] = n;
    return ar;
}

int main()
{
    int* someVals[6] = {0};  
    for(char i=0; i<6; i++) {
        someVals[i] = decToBinary(i + 1);
    }
    int* combined;
    combined = malloc(24*sizeof(int));
    int * ptr = combined;
    for(char i=0; i<6; i++) {
         memcpy(ptr, someVals[i], sizeof(int) * 4);
         ptr += 4;
    }
    for (char i=0; i<24; i++) printf("%d ", combined[i]); //=> 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 
    
    for (char i=0; i<6; i++) free(someVals[i]);
    free(combined);
    return 0;
}
```